# Can I install Google Chrome without typing lines of text?

Tags: installation, google-chrome

I am a complete dork when it comes to computers so maybe I should forget Linux altogether! I want to install Chrome, it has all my bookmarks etc. Is there an easy way without writing lines of code in places I cannot find?

Answer (score 3):

You can google for `Chrome`, go to Google official web site, download the appropriate .deb (probably 32bits), double click it and follow the instructions.

EDIT: Here is the download link: https://www.google.com/chrome?brand=CHMO#eula. Choose .deb for 32bits (or 64bits if you installed Ubuntu x64).

Answer (score 1):

Use your current browser to download Chrome from the [Google Chrome website](https://www.google.com/chrome?brand=CHMO). It should download a `.deb` file. The default download location for most downloads is the Downloads folder for your user account unless you changed it in your browser settings. Open a Terminal session with Control-Alt-T. Navigate to your Downloads folder with

```
cd ~/Downloads ;ls -l
```

which will also show the contents of the Downloads folder. You should see a file named something like `google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb` Get `dpkg` to handle the install by issuing

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Enter your user password when asked. `dpkg` will handle the install and place a launcher for Chrome in your Dash.

Comment: he could also just click the DEB from nautilus. It would save lots of typing he wants to avoid ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind I've not had much success getting `.deb` files to install properly though the GUI. And building some confidence in some basic Terminal actions will never hurt anyone ;)

Comment: @douggro you should probably check what went wrong with your .deb specific installation, because I believe the GUI executes exactly the same thing as your terminal code. I'm a big fan of terminal commands myself, but I believe they should be used to make things easier, more automatic... unnecessary complications should be avoided, specially for casual users.